# Python - World Bank Data , transpose

Tags: python, dataframe

how can i transpose the data via Pandas Library( Python ) , thank you so much

When i want to transpose the the data i cannot manage the result like below

My data frame s name is df , columns names are mentioned below.

**CURRENT DATA**

**TOPIC , COVENTRY, CODE, CURRENCY,2000, 2001,2002,2003**

---

Inflatio,               United Kingdom ,   UK,   GBP,   x   ,   x ,   x

**DESIRED DATA**

**COVENTRY         , CODE, CURRENCY,YEAR, INFLATION**

---

United Kingdom , UK,        GBR,   2000 ,    X

United Kingdom , UK,        GBR,   2001 ,      X

United Kingdom , UK,        GBR,   2002 ,      X

I want to transpose the df via panda , thank you for your helps

Comment: Please post an example of your sample data, code demoing what you've tried, and any errors. In general, in pandas, you can transpose a frame via `df.T` where `df` is a `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: thank you so much for your message. i have tried to update the desc. i cannot upload any pic unfortunately I am new and cannot allowed to upload. the dataframes name is df

Comment: It looks like you want a melt, not a transpose. [Check out the docs for `pd.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"TOPIC":["Inflatio"],"COVENTRY":["United Kingdom"],"CODE":["UK"],"CURRENCY":["GBP"],"2000":["x"],"2001":["x"],"2002":["x"],"2003":["x"]})

out = df.melt(id_vars=list(df.columns[:4]),value_vars=["2000","2001","2002","2003"],var_name='YEAR',value_name="INFLATION")
```

**Out**:

```
      TOPIC        COVENTRY CODE CURRENCY     YEAR     INFLATION
0  Inflatio  United Kingdom   UK      GBP     2000     x
1  Inflatio  United Kingdom   UK      GBP     2001     x
2  Inflatio  United Kingdom   UK      GBP     2002     x
3  Inflatio  United Kingdom   UK      GBP     2003     x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.stack()`/`.unstack()`:

```py
out = (
    df.set_index(["COUNTRY", "CODE", "TOPIC", "CURRENCY"])
    .stack()
    .unstack("TOPIC")
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_3": "YEAR"})
    .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
          COUNTRY CODE CURRENCY  YEAR Inflation
0  United Kingdom   UK      GBP  2000        x1
1  United Kingdom   UK      GBP  2001        x2
2  United Kingdom   UK      GBP  2002        x3
3  United Kingdom   UK      GBP  2003        x4
```